# Using Bootstrap navs into Angular2 component

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm trying to use Bootstrap's navs into my Angular 2 app.

I followed the example (copy / paste) in the Bootstrap docs (https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#javascript-behavior). I've included all the required CSS and JS in the .angular-cli.json file

```
 "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    ....
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.css",
    ....
  ],
  "scripts": [
    ....
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ]
```

but, even if it is rendered correctly, events on click are not handled (nothing happens on view).

I wouldn't use ng-boostrap, only if necessary. If someone could also explain how external 3rd party javascript libs (no typescript, just vanilla JS) could be used inside A2+ apps, I would appreciate.

**EDIT**

I think be helpful to know that the component in which the navbar is nested is dynamically created in a different moment from app loading (so when the scripts are executed). Could it be the reason why no click handler is bound to elements? If it so, how can I fix this?

**EDIT 2**

I've tried to use Boostrap in a component that has not been loaded at runtime (in the app-root component)... And works. So, why in a dynamically created component at runtime, this is not working anymore?

Comment: so your are not able to see bootstrap related classes working ? thats means <div class="container"> something like this is not getting rendered in bootstrap style?

Comment: nope, everything is rendered well with bootstrap's classes, but is the javascript behaviour that is not working and no errors are shown in the console

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap 4 beta and alpha are currently having problems with popper.js.
Personally I had to use Bootstrap 3 instead for my angular 4 project.

Check your console for misfiring javascript.

EDIT

These are the errors I get in my console when trying to run it.
[popper error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP5lO.png)

EDIT2

I don't think load time is relevant as long as the javascript is loaded by the time it should be used on the html.
If this is not the case maybe lifecycle hooks can help you. https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Nothing is shown in the console while trying to fire a click event on nav buttons... in the docs is said that navs does not depends on popper.js, so i didn't include it as a dependency

Comment: Interesting, when I attempted to use Bootstrap 4 both alpha 6 and beta by installing with npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta it visibly misfired in the console. this might be fixed or partially fixed for beta2 installed with npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 though, I have not testet that version.

Comment: it seems that no events handler are attached to the elements: getEventListeners(($('#pills-home-tab')[0])) and getEventListeners(($('.nav-item')[0])) return both an empty object

Comment: Are you sure that you are not getting anything like this? [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP5lO.png)

Comment: nope. I edited my question with new info, maybe that's why im not getting any error

Comment: EDIT 2: i think that load time could be relevant because it tries to target a bounch of elements (nav elements) that are not already been created when the script is loaded...